# Extracting latitude/longitude from NetCDFs that don't have latitude/longitude variables

Tags: python, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap

I have a NetCDF file (`ERO`) that doesn't have latitude/longitude as explicit variables. When I call `ERO.variables.keys()`, it returns

```
odict_keys(['FCST_ERO_Surface_FULL', 'OBS_ALL_A365324_FULL_MAX_49'])
```

When I call `ERO.dimensions.items()`, it returns

```
('lat', <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lat', size = 276)
('lon', <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lon', size = 721)
```

When I call `ERO`, it returns

```
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>
root group (NETCDF4 data model, file format HDF5):
    FileOrigins: File /export/hpc-lw-dtbdev5/merickson/ERO_verif/ERO_verif_day1_ALL//grid_stat_ALL_ERO_s2017082712_e2017082812_vhr09_240000L_20170828_120000V_pairs.nc generated 20191121_050829 UTC on host hpc-lw-dtbdev5.ncep.noaa.gov by the MET grid_stat tool
    MET_version: V8.1
    MET_tool: grid_stat
    model: WRF
    obtype: ANALYS
    Projection: LatLon
    lat_ll: 25.000000 degrees_north
    lon_ll: -129.800000 degrees_east
    delta_lat: 0.090000 degrees
    delta_lon: 0.090000 degrees
    Nlat: 276 grid_points
    Nlon: 721 grid_points
    dimensions(sizes): lat(276), lon(721)
    variables(dimensions): float32 FCST_ERO_Surface_FULL(lat,lon), float32 OBS_ALL_A365324_FULL_MAX_49(lat,lon)
    groups:
```

These lat/lon variables clearly exist, but I have no idea how to access them to visualize them on a basemap. Every NetCDF/basemap tutorial that I've looked at uses NetCDF files that have lat and lon variables. Hope I explained this clearly, and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you'll need to create your own `lat` and `lon` coordinates variables from the global attributes information.

Comment: e.g. based on the information given as global attributes, you could calculate latitude as `lat = np.linspace(25, 25+0.09*276, 276)`.

Comment: Thank you both! I created lat/lon using @MrFuppes formula and it's plotting now.